# Installation of Maven 3.2.1 is not terminating

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I try to set up a new Hudson (3.3.2) with Maven (3.2.1), but installation of Maven is not terminating.

**Configuration of Maven:**

[image: configuration of Maven]

**Job log:**

```
Gestartet durch Benutzer anonymous
[...]
Unpacking http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.1-bin.zip to C:\Users\dur\.hudson\tools\Maven_3.2.1 on Hudson
```

**Created files:**

```
.hudson
    tools
        Maven_3.2.1
             apache-maven-3.2.1
                 boot
                     plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar
```

All other files are not unpacked. But it is no network problem, because I can manually download and unpack `apache-maven-3.2.1-bin.zip` without any problem.

**Environment:**

- Windows 7
- Java 8 (also with Java 7)
- Hudson 3.3.2 (also with 3.3.3)
- Legacy Maven 2 job type Plugin 3.0.2

In the year 2014 I set up a Hudson (3.1.2) with Maven 3.0.4 successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work-around is to install Maven manually and use this installation, see [The Hudson Book](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch03.html#section-configure-maven):

> **Use an existing Installation**
>   Specify a Name and add the path to your Maven install in the MAVEN_HOME input control.

Configuration:

[image: Maven configuration]